# Debugging dotnet angular template web application in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am attempting to debug a web application in VS Code. I created the application following using dotnet new angular. I added the this application to a solution. The application builds and runs just fine. I can debug the application by attaching to it. But when I try to run the application in debug mode I get the following exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll

As a sanity check I added a console application to solution and tried to debug that. Debugging the console application works just fine. So then I tried creating a dotnet core mvc like so:

```
dotnet new mvc -n try-me -o try-me
```

I added an launch configuration and it debugs just fine. So this looks like maybe a problem with just the angular template. Has anyone else gotten this template to debug? Here's my launch.json. The configuration for ".NET Core Launch (web)" is the one in question.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [   

    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/jollies/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/jollies.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "internalConsole"
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/cars-webapp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/cars-webapp.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/cars-webapp",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
            },
            "osx": {
                "command": "open"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "xdg-open"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web-try me)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/try-me/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/try-me.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/try-me",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
            },
            "osx": {
                "command": "open"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "xdg-open"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to debug the client-side code. Usually to do that you need a plugin in your preferred browser in order to communicate to the IDE. Have you checked [Debug > Install Additional Debuggers...](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_11#_debugging) ? For example [this seems to be the Chrome extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome).

Comment: @omacarena - that's not it at all. I want to launch the dotnet webapp (the server) in the debugger. The client is not the issue at all.

Comment: Then you might be lucky adding the following to project.json `"buildOptions": {
  "debugType": "portable",
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true
},` as instructed [here](http://fizzylogic.nl/2016/11/22/ASP-NET-Core-debugging-tips-for-Visual-Studio-Code/) in order to get the symbols and pdb file. I think Visual Studio Code is more like an editor that you can customize with plugins. You might have a hard time with some tasks. You can also try installing [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15).

Comment: Sorry I was not clear but the project in question was a csproj type, not the older project.json type. Also, I do no thing this is a build problem, since I can run the application and attach to it and debug it, symbols and everything.

Comment: Yes you are right, you already stated that you can attach to it. `AggregateException` is an exception that holds multiple exceptions. For example when working with Tasks, EF. You can look at `AggregateException.InnerExceptions` to see if those underlying exceptions mean something.